# creating loading spinner in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

okay so basically, when i hit the register button on my register page, it takes a few seconds to get to the stripe page. I want to add a spinner for the time it takes to get to the stripe page, basically that limbo period. I am new to react, so not sure how to do this. Is this possible?

Here's my registration page:

```
   import React from 'react'

import './RegistrationForm.css'

import { Alert, Button, Form, Input } from 'antd'
import { AuthorizationHome } from '../models'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as routes from '../routes'
import facades from '../facades'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { useState } from "react";
import {createCheckoutSession} from '../Stripepayment/checkout'
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';


let firestore = firebase.firestore()

const FormItem = Form.Item


var userIDStripeSubmit = ""
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
  }

  
  
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) return
      const email = this.props.form.getFieldValue('email')
      const passwordOne = this.props.form.getFieldValue('password1')
      const firstName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('First Name')
      const lastName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Last Name')
      const companyName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Company Name')

      const {
        history,
      } = this.props

      AuthorizationHome.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
        .then((authUser) => facades.userFacade().doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, email))

        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({'error': error})
        })



        // adding into profiledata collection


            // var userID = ""
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if(user) {
                
                console.log(user.uid)
                userIDStripeSubmit = user.uid

                  console.log("userid inside firebase auth is" + user.uid)

                        //  var firstNameFromField = 
                          firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
                            firstname: firstName,
                            lastname: lastName,
                            companyname: companyName,
                            accountStatus: "inactive",
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            alert(error.message);
                        });
                        createCheckoutSession(user.uid)
              }
              })
             
              // firestore collection query
                
    })
  }

  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
  }

  compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password1')) {
      callback('Passwords do not match!');
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['password2'], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  }


  

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form
    const { error } = this.state
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  hideRequiredMark={true} className="registration-form" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
        { error && <Alert type="error" message={error.message}/> }

      
       
        <FormItem label="Email" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'Invalid email address',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your email address',
            }],
          })(
            <Input placeholder="Enter email" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        

{/*  */}

        <FormItem label="First Name" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('First Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your First Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Last Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Last Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Last Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem label="Company Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Company Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Company Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password1', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please choose a password',
            }, {
              validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem label="Confirm Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password2', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password',
            }, {
              validator: this.compareToFirstPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur} placeholder="Confirm password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" id="submitButton">Register</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegistrationForm);
export default withRouter(WrappedRegistrationForm)
```

i appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another component named Spinner with the gif image and prop which control the rendering of image.

```
const Spinner = ({ loading }) => {
    if (!loading) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
          <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </Spinner>
    );
};
```

And create a state variable with default value false which you need to set it to true when you are registering. Set it back to false after the registering is finished.

```
let firestore = firebase.firestore()

const FormItem = Form.Item


var userIDStripeSubmit = ""
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    isRegistering: false,
  }

  
  
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isRegistering: true });
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) return
      const email = this.props.form.getFieldValue('email')
      const passwordOne = this.props.form.getFieldValue('password1')
      const firstName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('First Name')
      const lastName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Last Name')
      const companyName = this.props.form.getFieldValue('Company Name')

      const {
        history,
      } = this.props

      AuthorizationHome.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
        .then((authUser) => {
       this.setState({ isRegistering: false });
       return facades.userFacade().doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, email);
    })

        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({ 'error': error, isRegistering: false })
        })



        // adding into profiledata collection


            // var userID = ""
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if(user) {
                
                console.log(user.uid)
                userIDStripeSubmit = user.uid

                  console.log("userid inside firebase auth is" + user.uid)

                        //  var firstNameFromField = 
                          firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(user.uid).set({
                            firstname: firstName,
                            lastname: lastName,
                            companyname: companyName,
                            accountStatus: "inactive",
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            alert(error.message);
                        });
                        createCheckoutSession(user.uid)
              }
              })
             
              // firestore collection query
                
    })
  }

  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
  }

  compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password1')) {
      callback('Passwords do not match!');
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['password2'], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  }
}

const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegistrationForm);
export default withRouter(WrappedRegistrationForm)
```

And Finally add your spinner container inside your render function.

```
render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form
    const { error, isRegistering } = this.state
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  hideRequiredMark={true} className="registration-form" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
        { error && <Alert type="error" message={error.message}/> }

      
        <Spinner loading={isRegistering} />
        <FormItem label="Email" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'Invalid email address',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your email address',
            }],
          })(
            <Input placeholder="Enter email" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        

{/*  */}

        <FormItem label="First Name" colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('First Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your First Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Last Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Last Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Last Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem label="Company Name" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('Company Name', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please enter your Company Name',
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Company Name"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>


        <FormItem label="Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password1', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please choose a password',
            }, {
              validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem label="Confirm Password" colon={false}  style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
          {getFieldDecorator('password2', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password',
            }, {
              validator: this.compareToFirstPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur} placeholder="Confirm password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" id="submitButton">Register</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer! I've edited my question to show what I did based on your answer, but doesn't seem to be working. could you give me some advice?

Comment: Have you applied css as well? Are you getting any error? What is happening? I just saw that you are using bootstrap spinner so I updated the spinner with the bootstrap spinner. You don't need to apply css anymore.

Comment: i actually defined `Spinner` twice. I apologize, your answer did help. Thank you

Comment: I've asked another question (you can find on my page) to do basically the same thing but on another page. However, it is not letting me use render statements inside the js page like it is this page. If you are open to looking, i would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Can you give me the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223558/creating-loading-spinner-in-between-page-load-react